# How to decode JSON-like JavaScript Object Literal Strings

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having trouble decoding an array of strings from what I thought was JSON.

```
var result = [
  "{gene: 'PEX2', go_bp: '0.766500871709', CombinedPvalue: '9.999999995E-4'}",
  "{gene: 'PEX5', go_bp: '0.766472586087', CombinedPvalue: '9.999999995E-4'}",
  "{gene: 'PEX7', go_bp: '0.766386859737', CombinedPvalue: '9.999999995E-4'}"
];
```

You can see that there are 3 gene-related strings of JavaScript object literals, each encoded as a string. How can I decode these?

I tried `JSON.parse` but it gives me an error.

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) 
    console.log(JSON.parse(result[i]));
```

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token g`.

Is there a simple way?

Comment: What you have is not JSON. Seems like strings containing JS object literals. The best solution would be to fix the code that generates these strings.

Comment: It is an array of almost-JSON.  See http://json.org/ for proper format.

Comment: JSON string should be in this format: `{"key": "value"}` not `{key : "value"}`.

Comment: It's also likely that you don't want to quote the numeric values.

Answer (score 5):

Since this is valid javascript, you can use `Function()` to return a new instance of the object by creating an anonymous function and then immediately executing it.  Unlike the other answer with `eval()`, you don't have to declare a variable and assign the object literal to that variable in the string passed to eval - everything you need can be done cleanly in one line.

```js
var result = [
    "{gene: 'PEX2', go_bp: '0.766500871709', CombinedPvalue: '9.999999995E-4'}",
    "{gene: 'PEX5', go_bp: '0.766472586087', CombinedPvalue: '9.999999995E-4'}",
    "{gene: 'PEX7', go_bp: '0.766386859737', CombinedPvalue: '9.999999995E-4'}"
];

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    // create function that returns the obj literal
    // and call it immedieately.
    var obj = new Function( 'return ' + result[i] + ';' )();
    document.write('gene: ' + obj.gene + ' <br />');
}
```

Comment: Excellent use of Function to avoid an eval.

Comment: It's not really avoiding an eval, it's just using another way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

What you have is not JSON, but Javascript objects in text form. You can convert them to Javascript objects with `eval()`:

```js
    var result = [
      "{gene: 'PEX2', go_bp: '0.766500871709', CombinedPvalue: '9.999999995E-4'}",
      "{gene: 'PEX5', go_bp: '0.766472586087', CombinedPvalue: '9.999999995E-4'}",
      "{gene: 'PEX7', go_bp: '0.766386859737', CombinedPvalue: '9.999999995E-4'}"
    ];

    var f;
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        eval("f = "+result[i]);
        console.log(f.gene);
    }
```

Note: `eval` is generally held to be evil. In this case it's safe enough if you're absolutely sure that the source array will only ever hold data, and no code.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON format requires double quotes around property names. Your sample data lacks these quotes, and this is not valid JSON.

It also requires double quoted values, not single quoted.

Try something like this:

```
   '{"gene": "PEX2", "go_bp": "0.766500871709", "CombinedPvalue": "9.999999995E-4"}',
```